# Correctly saving a plot with the finalise_plot function of the bbplot package

Tags: r, ggplot2

what happens is that when I save a plot with "finalyse_plot" the text labels become small and it is impossible to adjust the width. I have seen that this only happens when I add new fonts from google fonts to the charts. I appreciate any help and advice.

I attach an image and the codes used [[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VXs54.jpg)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R1GT5.jpg)

```
library(sysfonts)
library(showtextdb)
library(showtext)
library(ggtext)

font_add_google(name = "Alice",family =  "alice",db_cache = FALSE)#requiere internet
showtext_auto()

font_add_google(name = "Playfair",family =  "playfair",db_cache = FALSE)#requiere internet
showtext_auto()

 a <- ggplot(data = recuento) +  geom_sf(aes(fill = Leyenda), color = "black")+
  xlab("Longitud")+
  ylab("Latitud")+
  labs(title ="PBI per cápita por país en 2019",
       subtitle ="Valores medidos en PPA = 2017 international $",
       fill =" ",
       caption = "Fuente:Banco Mundial. Elaborado por @cpulica_pe\nGráfico:Diego Jesus | Data: Antony Alvarez") +theme_minimal() + theme_void(base_size = 20)
a


mapa19 <- a  + scale_fill_manual(values = color) + theme(legend.position = c( .1, .3),
                                            legend.key.size = unit(5, 'cm'),
                                            legend.key.width =unit(1, 'cm'),
                                            legend.key.height = unit(0.1, 'cm'),
                                            legend.text = element_text(size = 18, family = "Losa de Zilla"),
                                            plot.title =element_text(family =  "alice", face = "bold",size = 40, hjust = 0.50),
                                            plot.subtitle =element_text(family =  "playfair",size = 18, hjust = 0.50),
                                            plot.caption = element_text(family =  "playfair",hjust = 0, size = 12))

mapa19

library(bbplot)
#Guardamos 
finalise_plot(plot_name = mapa19,
              source = " ",
              save_filepath = "C:/Users/HP SUPPORT/Desktop/Gráficos Cosa Pública/mapa19.jpeg",
              width_pixels = 1000,
              height_pixels = 500)
```

I tried to save the graphics with the ggsave package but it comes out the same. Besides, I don't use it because it gives me lower quality graphics compared to "finalyse_plo". As I said at the beginning, this only happens when I add new text fonts to the graphics.

Comment: First, IMHO there is no reason to use `finalise_plot` as under the hood the plots are still saved by calling `ggsave`: https://github.com/bbc/bbplot/blob/82af5952230c695bd317d7786587cfffea7f7621/R/finalise_plot.R#L6-L7.

Comment: Concerning the issue with the font size. When using `showtext` (or fonts in general)  you have take care of the `dpi`,  i.e. by default `ggsave` exports plots with `dpi=300` while `showtext_auto` will default to 96 dpi. As a result fonts appear about 3 times smaller. To fix try with adding `showtext_opts(dpi = 300)`. See https://www.christophenicault.com/post/understand_size_dimension_ggplot2/ and https://github.com/yixuan/showtext/issues/51#issuecomment-1199000169

Comment: Hello, Stefan. I applied "showtext_opts (dpi = 300)" and for saving I used ggsave directly, the problem is solved. Thank you very much.